# Visual Code , PHP and configuration not found

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

My Visual Code not recognize the PHP's configuration.

[image: json]

But, It recognizes the file.

[image]

And the problem is that I can't edit PHP configurations and I can't use PHP Intelephense plugin. Also the editor not recognize variables.

Where is the problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: you haven't provided enough information here. Its quite unclear what the question is.

Comment: Sorry. I edited It.